# How can I require enforcement on @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm creating a SpringBoot application and part of its functionality is create users, and conversations between these users. There are the following entities created..

1. User (person involved in conversation)
2. Conversation (record holding the owning user of the conversation)
3. ConversationUser (record holding the user involved and to which conversation)

The trouble is, My JpaRepository.save(ConversationUser) let's me insert a record with a non-existing user reference. How can I enforce this ConversationUser to only be able to insert if the user associated has an existing ID?

I've tried using `@ManyToOne` and `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on ConversationUser to try and enforce the existence of a real record, but without success.

`User.class`

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    protected UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected char[] password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String firstName, lastName;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String email;
}
```

`ConversationUser.class`

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                "conversation_id",
                "user_id"
        })
})
public class ConversationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "conversation_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Conversation conversation;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_id"))
    private User user;

}
```

I expect that because of the way `ConversationUser.user` is setup, if I try to run the following test, that it would generate an exception. However, this test fails and no exception is generated. I've checked the database, and the row is getting inserted.

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testFakeAttendeeOfConversation() {
    UserModel fakeUserModel = generateRandomUser();
    fakeUserModel.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    conversationService.createConversation(new JwtUser(userA), Collections.singleton(fakeUserModel.getId()));
}
```

The function that calls the ConversationUser repository interface `(extends JpaRepository<ConversationUser, UUID>)` is the following..

```
@Transactional
public void addUserToConversation(JwtUser jwtRequestUser, Conversation conversation, UUID attendeeId) {
    User attendee = User.builder().id(attendeeId).build();
    ConversationUser conversationUser = ConversationUser.builder()
            .conversation(conversation)
            .user(attendee)
            .build();
    conversationUserRepository.save(conversationUser);
}
```

Does anyone know why I am able to insert any `ConversationUser` even if the user referenced in it does not exist in the database?

Comment: can you provide your java code where you are saving `ConversationUser` object

Comment: That's mentioned at the very end. It's the function `addUserToConversation`. A `ConversationUser` is built and saved with the `save` function from `conversationUserRepository`